# Pass database connection settings to function

Tags: c#, database, connection

Is there a class or an interface in c#, that represents database connection settings?
I want to pass the connection settings to a function like:

```
public DoWorkOnDb(IDbConnectionSettings settings)
{
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(settings.ConnectionString);
   ...
}
```

What I do not want to do is:

- pass a connection, because the function should handle the connection on her own
- pass a connectionstring, because then you could pass all types of strings
- pass multiple strings like server, database, user, password, because then I have to build the connection string in the function.

Comment: Out of interest, what stops `settings.ConnectionString` being a non-valid string?

Comment: @Daniel Kelley: Nothing, but it I fell better with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you need [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).
Then you need to call [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.tostring.aspx) or [TryGetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trygetvalue.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the [`ConnectionStringSettingsCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-class which contains [`ConnectionStringSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has a [`ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.connectionstring.aspx) or [`ProviderName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.providername.aspx) property.

Maybe you want to combine it with the [`DbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd pass a func:

```
public DoWorkOnDb(Func<SqlConnection> connectionFactory)
{
    using (var connection = connectionFactory())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would't create an anonymous factory method for the entire connection :/

Comment: Because I prefer to let the concrete DB provider implementation decide how to manage the connection life-cycle.

Comment: So it's the "using" that's bothering you? I did have second thoughts about that.

Comment: I mean that if you're working with some kind of abstraction, the whole abstraction should have its own connection factory.